# Swift: Protocol `static var foo: Self` and enums

Tags: swift, enums, swift-protocols

### Simplified example

Take a look at this simple protocol

```
protocol FooOwner {
    static var foo: Self { get }
}
```

I would like an enum to conform to said protocol, and in my opinion this ought to work, since the static syntax `SomeTypeConformingToFooOwner.foo` should result in an instance of `SomeTypeConformingToFooOwner` and in the case where `SomeTypeConformingToFooOwner` is a enum.

```
enum Foo: FooOwner { // Type 'Foo' does not conform to protocol FooOwner
    case foo
}
```

The workaround is this ugly thing:

```
protocol FooOwner {
    static var fooOwner: Self { get }
}

enum Foo: FooOwner {
    case foo
    static var fooOwner: Foo {
        return Foo.foo
    }
}
```

Do you have a nicer workaround for enum conforming to protocols with static vars?

### Real use case

```
protocol StringConvertibleError: Swift.Error {
    static var invalidCharactersError: Self { get }
}

protocol StringConvertibleErrorOwner {
    associatedtype Error: StringConvertibleError
}

protocol StringConvertible {
    var value: String { get }

    /// Calling this with an invalid String will result in runtime crash.
    init(validated: String)

    init(string value: String) throws

    static func validate(_ string: String) throws -> String
}

// MARK: - Default Implementation Constrained
extension StringConvertible where Self: CharacterSetSpecifying, Self: StringConvertibleErrorOwner {
    static func validate(_ string: String) throws -> String {
        guard Self.allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)) else {
            throw Error.invalidCharactersError
        }
        // Valid
        return string
    }
}

struct HexString: StringConvertible, CharacterSetSpecifying, StringConvertibleErrorOwner {

    static var allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.hexadecimal

    let value: String

    init(validated unvalidated: String) {
        do {
            self.value = try HexString.validate(unvalidated)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Passed unvalid string, error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

extension HexString {
    enum Error: StringConvertibleError {
        static var invalidCharactersError: Error {
            return Error.invalidCharacters
        }

        case invalidCharacters
    }
}
```

So it's the last part that I would like to change to:

```
extension HexString {
    enum Error: StringConvertibleError {
        case invalidCharacters
    }
}
```

Since I have many similar types to `HexString`.

Yes of course obviously I can use one shared Error enum, but I would like to have one specific enum per type.

Comment: `static var foo != case foo`

Comment: The workaround is not bad, assuming you use appropriate names. Is there something you want to solve with this approach? Maybe we can find an alternative.

Comment: @tikhonov-alexander Well yes I know... but it would be nice if Swift could support bridging different enums together by some common `case`. 

And yes, of course, I can use the `open enum` (e.g. `struct`), but I really want to use enums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SE-0280](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0280-enum-cases-as-protocol-witnesses.md) solves this - if accepted. It is currently in review.

## Edit 1

Great news, [SE-0280 has been accepted](https://forums.swift.org/t/accepted-se-0280-enum-cases-as-protocol-witnesses/34850).

Answer (score 0):

This might not fully match OP's issue, but as it seems somewhat related, I'm throwing it out there in case it helps.
In my case, I cared about some cases, but other cases could be ignored (or handled in a common way).
I admit my approach is not elegant and requires a lot of boiler plate, but it got me past a similar problem.

```swift
// Given these enums, we want a protocol that matches enums with
// 'foo' and 'bar' cases.
enum FooFriends {
    case foo // conforms
    case bar // conforms
    case baz // don't really care
}

enum FooBar {
    case foo // conforms
    case bar // conforms
}

// We wish we could do this:
protocol FooBarWish {
    case foo // or static var foo: Self { get }
    case bar // or static var bar: Self { get }
}

// Workaround
// the boiler plate
enum FooBarProxy {
    case foo
    case bar
    case other
}

protocol FooBarProtocol {
    func getProxy() -> FooBarProxy
}

extension FooFriends: FooBarProtocol {
    func getProxy() -> FooBarProxy {
        switch self {
        case .foo:
            return .foo
        case .bar:
            return .bar
        default:
            return .other
        }
    }
}

extension FooBar: FooBarProtocol {
    func getProxy() -> FooBarProxy {
        switch self {
        case .foo:
            return .foo
        case .bar:
            return .bar
        }
    }
}

// Usage
// Instead of the ideal case (which won't work)
let fooBarOrFooFriend1: FooBarWish = FooFriends.foo
let fooBarOrFooFriend2: FooBarWish = FooBar.bar

// We can get by with
let fooBarProxy1 = FooFriends.foo.getProxy()
let fooBarProxy2 = FooBar.bar.getProxy()

// Verification
func checkIt(_ foobar: FooBarProxy) {
    switch foobar {
    case .foo:
        print("it was foo")
    case .bar:
        print("it was bar")
    case .other:
        print("it was neither")
    }
}

checkIt(fooBarProxy1)
checkIt(fooBarProxy2)
// =>
// it was foo
// it was bar
```